# Problem in executing the routing_core.sql

Tags: pgrouting

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting": No such file or directory

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please explain your question in detail along with software details.

Comment: incomplete question. please close this

Answer (score 2):

your `$libdir` variable doesn't point to correct directory or that directory doesn't contain `librouting` file

easiest way to fix it is replace `$libdir` with real path to `librouting` file

Comment: how to check the $lib dir variable is pointing to correct directory ?

Comment: Using the shell (unix command line), you can just do "echo $libdir" (without the quotes)